# Is it true that, if $A\setminus B \subseteq C$, then $A\setminus C \subseteq B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Prove or provide counterexample for :

> If $A\setminus B \subseteq C$ then $A\setminus C \subseteq B$

My approach was, supposed $A\setminus B \subseteq C$, then let $x \in A\setminus B$, since $A\setminus B \subseteq C$, then $x \in C$. From there on I don't know what to do, please point me in the right direction. 
Thanks

Comment: I mean no disrespect by this, but this website is not a place where people will do your homework for you. Please edit the question to show your own attempt at the problem and where you get lost/what's confusing to you. There will be no judgements for not knowing how to do something but plenty of judgment for not trying!

Comment: @user52969 You are absolutely correct, OP could have at least dignified the question with whether or not they thought it was true or not!

Comment: Yeah sorry, this is my first time posting a question. I'll keep what you guys said in mind.

Comment: One approach to problems where we try to show the roles of two terms can be swapped, as is the case here with $B,C$, is to look for a way to rewrite the condition in a way that makes the symmetry of their roles evident.

Comment: Did any of the answers help, or are you still having trouble with this?  If the former, $\color{green}\checkmark$ the answer.  If the later, edit the question to include further thoughts.

Comment: The answers all helped. Thanks everyone for the answers and advices, hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S'pose $A/B \subset C$.

Let $x \in A/C$.  Then $x \not \in C$. Then $x \not \in A/B \subset C$.  But $x \in A \subset A/C$ while $x \not \in A/B \subset A$.  So $x \not: \not \in B$.  So $x \in B$.  So $A/C \subset B$.

Answer (score 0):

$$x\in A\setminus C\implies x\notin C\;\text{but}\;x\in A\implies x\notin A\setminus B\;\text{but}\;x\in A\implies x\in A\setminus B$$

Answer (score 0):

**Begin:** $A\setminus B\subseteq C$ means that any element which is in $A$ is *either* in $B$ or *else* it is in $C$.   That is $A\subseteq B\cup C$.

$$A\setminus B\subseteq C ~\implies~ A\subseteq B\cup C$$

**Next:** Show that the converse holds, then use an argument for symmetry.